# Statement of Purpose for going back to school years after graduating

Tags: graduate-admissions, statement-of-purpose

**Background**

It's a rather uneventful story, but I think nobody can come up with a relevant answer without knowing where I'm coming from. Thanks in advance for reading through this!

I finished my Bachelor studies in 2012 with a degree in Systems Engineering. My studies were supposed to be about robotics and industrial automation, but due to little to no financing (think Eastern Europe) it was 99% theoretical with 10 different courses in math.

Even before graduating I realised I had to start making money (getting me through university was definitely tough for the family) and started working as a freelance developer. Later on I got a full-time job offer several months before getting my diploma. The pay was way over what my parents were making, so it was a no-brainer to say "goodbye!" to my studies and settle for the Bachelor's degree. Fast forward seven years, I'm an engineering manager in tech company, with significant development experience. I've been thinking a lot about what I want to do in life, and realised that my job doesn't make me happy and I was always fascinated by other things. Neither management, nor architectural carreer tracks don't excite me.

I've asked myself: "Where can I find a match between my skills - building software - and what I'm interested in - healthcare, ageing, extending human lifespan?". That's how I came to a decision to study Bioinformatics and get a MS degree.

**Now to my questions for writing a Statement of Purpose:**

- Since my degree isn't in CS, but rather in Engineering, should I explain why I went into software development, rather than automation/robotics?
- How do I convey my fitness to finish an MS program? It's been a while since I was in an academic environment, but I've been taking MOOCs recently. Is it something which can help?
- How do I connect my work experience (software development) with the Bioinformatics?

Comment: I expanded the acronym SOP because I thought at first that it meant Standard Operating Procedure.  Welcome to the site!